# How to store static contents outside WildFly installation and access them via HTTP?

Tags: openshift, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm new to both Openshift (next gen) and WildFly

I'm currently writing an application that allows the user to upload images and let other view the images. In order for the images to survive server restart, I should put the images on persistence volume, which is outside the exploded WAR.

I have mounted persistent volume to `/data`.

**My question is:** how can I serve the images stored in `/data`?

- I know I can write a servlet to stream the files -- but I'd like to
  avoid this if possible
- I know that I can specify below code in jboss' `standalone.xml` - but I think `standalone.xml` will be wiped by Openshift once I deploy a new WAR file

  ```
  <handlers>
  <file name="ImagesDirHandler" follow-symlink="true" directory-listing="true" cache-buffers="1024" cache-buffer-size="1024" path="/data/images"/>
  </handlers>
  ```

Comment: Try using a Symlink?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've tried using symbolic link, but wildfly doesn't follow the symbolic link